# How do I match values based on an index value?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Sometimes I run across problems where information is in two datasets. Although cumbersome I use Access to pair the data and then export it to a CSV. Other times I use for loops to iterate through both lists and match data but it doesn't scale well.

I was wondering if there were more efficient methods in Python to "link" data. Below is an example of what I'm talking about

In this case one dataset contains the make and model, the other contains the country of origin. I'd like to be able to combine the data in sets A and B into one dataset for export, analysis etc.

```
A=[['Chevy','Suburban'],['Toyota','Camry'],['Honda','Civic']]
B=[['Chevy','America'],['Toyota','Japan'],['Honda','Japan']]

AB =[['Chevy','Suburban','America'],['Toyota','Camry','Japan'],['Honda','Civic','Japan']]
```

As always any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe something like this? `map(lambda x: x[0] + [x[1][1]], zip(A, B))`

Comment: In this case they're in order but in most cases they're not. The code looks handy though! I'm going to save it in my library of snippets

Answer (score 3):

I think you can consider using [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for this purpose:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> MakeOrigin = namedtuple('MakeOrigin', ['make', 'origin'])
>>> MakeModel = namedtuple('MakeModel', ['make', 'model'])
>>> A = [MakeModel('Chevy', 'Suburban'), MakeModel('Toyota', 'Camry'), MakeModel('Honda', 'Civic')]
>>> B = [MakeOrigin('Chevy', 'America'), MakeOrigin('Toyota', 'Japan'), MakeOrigin('Honda', 'Japan')]
>>> AB = [[a.make, a.model, b.origin] for a in A for b in B if a.make == b.make]
>>> AB
[['Chevy', 'Suburban', 'America'], ['Toyota', 'Camry', 'Japan'], ['Honda', 'Civic', 'Japan']]
```

It is more readable and allows more interesting operations.

---

Without using `namedtuple`:

```
>>> A=[['Chevy','Suburban'],['Toyota','Camry'],['Honda','Civic']]
>>> B=[['Chevy','America'],['Toyota','Japan'],['Honda','Japan']]
>>> 
>>> AB = [[a[0], a[1], b[1]] for a in A for b in B if a[0] == b[0]]
>>> AB
[['Chevy', 'Suburban', 'America'], ['Toyota', 'Camry', 'Japan'], ['Honda', 'Civic', 'Japan']]
```